# ElasticSearch partial phrase matching

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

I'm an ElasticNoob, but I've been playing around with some simple phrase matching as follows:

```
query: {
  match_phrase: {
    my_field: {
      query: "silly dogs playing about",
      slop:  100
    }
  }
}
```

But this only matches entries that have **all** 4 terms (silly, dogs, playing, about). Ideally it'd still match something like "silly dogs that are playing" which doesn't have the "about" keyword (it would get a lower score because of this).

This seems like a very common use case for a text search engine so I figured my Google-fu must be weak because I can't find anything about *partial* phrase matching in elastic search.

Can someone point me in the right direction here? Just to be clear:

- The *order* of keywords matters (`match_phrase` and `slop` allow us to do this)
- The *number* of keywords matched matters (`match_phrase` simply excludes items if *any* keywords are missing - this is not ideal for my situation)

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Recomended solution is:

> Instead of using proximity matching as an absolute requirement, we can
>   use it as a signal—as one of potentially many queries, each of which
>   contributes to the overall score for each document (see Most Fields).

Here you have article describing it: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/proximity-relevance.html

So your query would look like:

```
  query: {
    bool: {
      must: {
        match: {
          my_field: {
            query: "silly dogs playing about",
            minimum_should_match: "30%"
          }
        }
      },
      should: {
        match_phrase: {
          my_field: {
            query: "silly dogs playing about",
            slop:  50
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Ah, exactly what I'm looking for - thanks! Works a charm.

Answer (score -3):

You can use the variable call minimum_should_match to either specify the percentage of the words that needs to match or to specify how many words should match.

```
query: {
  match_phrase: {
    my_field: {
      query: "silly dogs playing about",
      slop:  100,
      minimum_should_match: "75%"
    }
  }
}
```

This would mean at least 3 of the 4 words would need to match for it to be a hit.

Comment: This won't work. `match_phrase` does not support `minimum_should_match` parameter.